# Como alterar a ordem de pesquisa do mysql sem recarregar a página?

Tags: php, mysql, aplicação-web

Tenho uma lista de produtos que é exibida em lista em ordem crescente.

Meu objetivo é fazer um checkbox que ao clicar, ela recarregue em ordem decrescente, talvez com um checkbox.

Mas para isso teria que ser sem recarregar a página toda.

```
    public function listImagesById(string $id):array{
        $result = $this->mysql->query("SELECT f.*,p.id as id_image FROM tbproductimages as f join tbproducts as p on f.id_product=p.id WHERE id_product = {$id}");
        $images = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $images;
    }
```

Na página em que são exibidas as informações, eu as exibo em uma tabela através de um foreach() após chamar a função no topo da página, como em:

```
  foreach($images as $image):
            
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?=$image['id']?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?=$image['nome']?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="<?=$imagePath.$image['name']?>" alt="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="" method='POST'>
                        <input type="hidden" name='id' value='<?=$image['id'];?>'>
                        <input type="submit" id='exclude-input' name='exclude-image-btn' value='Excluir'>

                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach?>
```

Como eu disse, a minha intenção seria colocar um filtro, como um checkbox que ao marcado inverteria a ordem em que as imagens são exibidas, com a query:

```
$result = $this->mysql->query("SELECT f.*,p.id as id_image FROM tbproductimages as f join tbproducts as p on f.id_product=p.id WHERE id_product = {$id} ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso, por favor? Grato desde já!

Comment: da uma olha no [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) que pode resolver esse problema

Comment: Você pode utilizar requisições [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) para isso, daí traz a tabela filtrada do seu backend, ou fazer um filter no frontend, mas daí tu teria que ter um objeto javascript com os dados do backend, o que seria meio que gambiarra, mas também funfa.

Answer (score -2):

Realizar consulta no banco sem atualizar, precisará utilizar algum método assíncrono.

Neste caso o [jQuery](https://jquery.com) consegue lidar bem com este trabalho.
Quando o processo é mais simples eu prefiro usar o `$.load` do jQuery, se necessitar de um detalhamento maior poderá utilizar o `$.ajax`, além de outras funções como `$.get` e `$.post`.

Veja um exemplo aplicado ao seu caso abaixo;

*Recomendo fortemente a utilização do prepared statement para evitar sql injection e  algo contra ataque XSS se for o caso.

```
<?php
//por default asc
$order = isset($_POST['order'] == "desc") ? $order = "desc" : $order = "asc";
//passe $order para o método e o utilize na consulta
$images = ...->listImagesById($id, $order);

foreach($images as $image):
    $table = "
    <tr>
        <td>{$image['id']}</td>
        <td>{$image['nome']}</td>
        <td><img src='{$imagePath.$image['name']}' alt=''></td>
        <td>
            <form action='' method='POST'>
                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='{$image['id']}'>
                <input type='submit' id='exclude-input' name='exclude-image-btn' value='Excluir'>

            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>";
}

if($_POST['ajax']) {
    die($table);
}
?>

<html>
    ...
    <input id="refreshTable" type="checkbox" />
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody id="tableAjax"><?=$table?></tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#refreshTable").on('change', function() {
                let sOrder = $(this).is(':checked') ? "desc" : "asc";
                $("#tableAjax").load("pagina.php", {ajax: true, order: sOrder}, function() {
                    console.log('loadCompleto');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```